# Hard Negative Mining in CNN Leading to Imbalanced Sample

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am working on deep learning for object detection (binary classification). I read from various sources that it is preferable to have a balanced training data. I was hoping if someone could link me to some papers that substantiate this claim ?
I ask because I am performing hard negative mining to augment my training set of negative samples. This however, will lead to an imbalanced training set as it will result in more negative than positive samples. Is there any way I can alleviate the problem of imbalanced training data ? And is hard negative mining a good idea in CNNs ?